# Change the order of executable commands on Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, path-variables

Sometimes I need to change the order of an executable command that only shares the name. Let me show you a simple example:

```
λ where find
C:\Windows\System32\find.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\find.exe
C:\cygwin64\bin\find.exe
```

On this case, the Windows's 'find' command is called instead of the other two (GNU findutils). My question is quite simple: which is the right way to change the order or set one of them as the first preference?

Comment: The first hit wins, put the path you want and you are good to go

Comment: On windows 8/10, when you edit path from environment variables, you get move up/down buttons to set priority. The one at top is preferred. @Marged already said it differently and simply.

Comment: To amend @fr0zenfyr answer: if you only need this temporarily you can create a script that does `set path=C:\Windows\System32;...`. Call it `fw.cmd` and run it once needed. Add fg and fc for git and cygwin. Don't forget the other path elements !

Answer (score 5):

Go to the environment variables definition of Windows and copy the existing entry for `PATH`. Create a new variable named `BASEPATH` and put all entries into it that *do not* belong to the list of paths where `find.exe` can be found.

Now create a file called `fwin.cmd` and put it somewhere on the PATH. The content of that file will look like this:

```
@echo off
SET PATH=C:\windows\system32;%BASEPATH%
ECHO Set path to search tools like find in Windows own folder
```

Create two files `fgit.cmd` and `fcyg.cmd` and change the PATH accordingly.

From time to time additionally installed applications will change your `PATH`. If this is the case you will need to add the new entries to the `BASEPATH`.

Depending on which `find.exe` you want, open a command line shell of Windows and call the corresponding cmd file. The path set by the batch will be local to the open shell, once you close it the setting will be gone.

You could also address the wanted find.exe directly but this means more typing and is probably not what you want:

```
dir C:\ /S | C:\Windows\System32\find.exe foo
```

Comment: Directories can be repeated in `PATH`, so just prepend the desired directory, e.g. `set "PATH=C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;%PATH%"`.

Comment: In general one might have a set of executables that needs to be switched in, with no way to arrange `PATH` to match the set without conflicts. This can be managed with batch-script wrappers or .LNK shell links (i.e. shortcuts) created in (or copied/symlinked to) a common directory. Add ".LNK" to the `PATHEXT` environment variable. Leave the start in directory empty in a link in order to inherit the working directory when run from the command prompt.

Comment: If a program calls `CreateProcessW` and allows it to search for the executable, then `CreateProcessW` will always search the application directory and system directories before searching `PATH`. So in general we cannot bypass a system executable such as "find.exe" unless there's a "find.exe" in the application directory (i.e. the directory that contains the executable of the current process). The CMD shell implements its own search that just uses `PATH`, so we have complete control in this case.

Comment: @ErykSun My objective was to describe a solution that is easy to implementiert and understand

Comment: See my first comment. There's no need for `BASEPATH`. It's simpler without it, and there's no maintenance requirement. The 2nd comment is somewhat complicated, but it's addressing the general problem of conflicting directories in a `PATH` search (e.g. if two directories contain many executables with the same name, and we need executables from both directories). We could instead create additional variables for the conflicting directories and always access their files as fully-qualified paths instead of searching (e.g. `"%SPAM_BIN%\eggs.exe"`).

Comment: I personally don't like to continuously prepend the existing path but the OP is free to adapt this

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by going in the environment variable, search for all path where your exe is and move up and down depending on the preferred order.
Of course this will affect other exe !!!

For this example below I add to move up and down in the system variables `PATH` and `mypath`.

```bash
C:\Users\duser > where sort
C:\Windows\System32\sort.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\sort.exe
```

to get

```bash
C:\Users\duser > where sort
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\sort.exe
C:\Windows\System32\sort.exe
```